# How to convert string object into array of object?

Tags: javascript

```
let input = "{"proname":"8974PP"}"
```

i want to convert the above into array of object like ***[{proname:8974PP}]***

Comment: That's not even valid javascript. Do you want to start with `let input = '{"proname":"8974PP"}'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.parse` is your friend. Just wrap the result in square brackets.

```
const output = [JSON.parse(input)];
```